# Instantiating of a class derived from a generic one that has params in its constructor

Tags: c#, generics, constructor

I have this generic class `Foo<>` with two constructors. One of them accepts variable number of parameters using `params` keyword. The other nongeneric class `Bar` is derived from `Foo<>`. The problem is that `Bar` does not accept instantiating with constructor that has`params`.

This is a sample:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Foo<T> where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        private Foo() { }
        public Foo(params T[] list) : this() { }
    }
    class Bar : Foo<int> { }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Foo<int> foo = new Foo<int>(1, 2); // it compiles
            Bar bar = new Bar(1, 2); // but CS1729 here!
        }
    }
}
```

It gives a compiler error:

> [Error    CS1729](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1729): 'Bar' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructors aren't inherited in C#. If you don't specify a constructor, the compiler will generate a parameterless constructor for you, which calls the base class's parameterless constructor. If your class derives from a base class which doesn't have any non-private parameterless constructors, the compiler errors.

So your plan of getting `Bar` to inherit the `Foo` constructor which takes a `params T[]` will never work.

It turns out that what's happening here is that the compiler has realised that it can generate a parameterless constructor which calls the base `Foo(params T[])` constructor, by passing an empty array. [See it here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTABAMQPZIDwBUB8BYAUAbzzmLgAcAnASwDcBDAFwFNEUAKASjnzgF8iSoAZhZJWpWuVoBbAM5x0AbQC6cADaUZ9TiDj0AFho5deePrlhwAQhLg7kaSgDt6mYzyA===).

In your case, you need to give `Bar` its own constructor:

```
class Bar : Foo<int>
{
    public Bar(params int[] list) : base(list) { }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing implementing that constructor from `Foo` in `Bar`:

```
class Foo<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
        private Foo() { }
        public Foo(params T[] list) : this() { }
}

class Bar : Foo<int>
{
    public Bar(params int[] list) : base(list) { }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with generics. It's just that constructors are not, by default, inherited in child classes. The fact that `Foo<int>` has a `params int[]` constructor doesn't automatically mean `Bar` has it too:

> Not all members of a base class are inherited by derived classes. The following members are not inherited:
>
> - Instance constructors, which you call to create a new instance of the class. Each class must define its own constructors.

(from the [C# Inheritance Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/inheritance) on MS Docs)

You'll have to define a specific constructor for `Bar` and chain the base call to it:

```
 public Bar (params int[] list) : base(list) {}
```